# Peer connection rate in a Torrent application

Tags: python, tcp, connection, python-3.5, torrent

I've been working on a torrent application like popcorn time in python for a while now and it's working quite well. I've been having some issues connecting to peers though.

About 90% of the peers I get from either DHT, UDP/HTTP Tracker or PeerExchange are unreachable..
I try to connect but it simply tells me it refuses the connection. Is this expected behaviour? I understand that the peer could be offline, but 90% is alot.. 
It means I need 100 potential peers to have maybe 10 connection after trying all. This doesn't correspond to for example uTorrent which can have like 13 potential peers and connect to 10 of them.

Just in case you guys think it might have something to do with my connect method or the parsing of the responses;
Connect method:

```
def connect(self):
    try:
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.settimeout(self.con_timeout)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.connect((self.host, self.port))
        return True
    except (socket.timeout, ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionAbortedError,    ConnectionResetError, OSError):
        return False
```

Ip/port parsing:

```
def uri_from_bytes(data):
    ip = socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET, data[0: 4])
    offset, port = read_ushort(data, 4)
    return 'tcp://' + ip + ":" + str(port)

def read_ushort(buffer, offset):
    ushort = struct.unpack_from('!H', buffer, offset)
    offset += 2
    return offset, ushort[0]
```

If anyone has any experience developing a torrent client or simply has an idea of what might be wrong; help is appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend using WireShark and compare to a working client. Be aware that some peers only accepts uTP/UDP or encrypted connections, but I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: Yeh that is something I mean to do. I also thought that most clients prefer uTP but still support tcp connections right?

Comment: Yes, most peers accept TCP and unencrypted connections, so peers are mostly unconnectable because they are NATed and don't have the incomming port forwarded. There are also a risk to maliciously be given bogus peers.

Comment: I guess being NATed would explain some, since uTP doesn't have that problem if I'm correct. I pretty sure the peers are okay since theyre comming from different sources and the result is the same for different torrents. Maybe I should implement uTP.. Seems pretty difficult though

Comment: There is still problems to connect to NATed uTP. It's possible if the other peer has very recently tried to connect (<~20s) or by using the `ut_holepunch` extension. uTP is usually implemented by using https://github.com/bittorrent/libutp